# How to config file name of logger in each class in scrapy?

Tags: python, logging, scrapy

I have used scrapy for several months.Several weeks ago,I started to use file to record log information.I wrote `log-to-file` function as this:

```
def logging_to_file(file_name):
import logging
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging

filename = '%s-log.txt' % file_name
import os

if os.path.isfile(filename):
    os.remove(filename)
configure_logging(install_root_handler=False)
logging.basicConfig(
    filename=filename,
    filemode='a',
    format='%(levelname)s: %(message)s',
    level=logging.DEBUG
)
return logging.getLogger()
```

Then,in each scrapy spider class,I use `logger = logging_file.logging_to_file('./logs/xxx-%s' % time.strftime('%y%m%d'))` in `__init__` function to customize log file name.
Something went wrong today,I found if I wrote two scrapy classes in one `.py` file,and after I started spider of the second class,the log file was also  named by the file name which is given in the first class!
I think this is caused by python log rule,but I don't know how to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand what your question is but in general you don't have to create any functions or anything to configure your logger.

What you should do create a logger and assign it a `FileHandler` and then just use your created logger to log your info.

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('mylogger')  # skip name for global rules
fh = logging.FileHandler(LOG_FILE_DIR, mode='a')
logger.addHandler(fh)
```

You can put this anywhere that gets executed on program startup, like `__init__.py` or something.

Now when you want to log something just:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('mylogger')
logger.error("error happened, oh no!")
```

Official Python logging tutorial can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial)